# Why is my algorithm to find merging point in link list not working?

Tags: java, algorithm

My approach was brute force approach. I would take each of the node from 2nd list and compare with one node of 1st list at each iteration

```
static int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode head1, SinglyLinkedListNode head2) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode temp1= head1;
    SinglyLinkedListNode temp2= head2;
    int data=0;
    while(temp1!=null){
        while(temp2!=null){
            if(temp1==temp2){
                data=temp2.data;
                break;
            }
            else
                temp2=temp2.next;
        }
        temp1=temp1.next;
    }
    return data;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: What's a merge node?  a node that is shared in the two lists?

Comment: this probably works. can you give us an example that you think it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by merging point, but when you set temp1=temp1.next; you should probably also go back to the beginning of temp2 by temp2 = head2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The merging point is basically where two linked list points to the same node. And yes let me try then